# Auto calling jsp from javascript with interval time

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have 2 different jsp pages i need to call those one by one
like slide show.
so my code is

```
     function switchPages(){ //here common function to call from my jsp file

    setInterval(pageOne, 20000);
    setInterval(pageSecond, 20000);
}

function pageOne(){

    var path='graph1.jsp';
    window.location.href = path;

}

function pageSecond(){

    var path='graph2.jsp';
    window.location.href = path;

}
```

it gets an ambiguity when my setInterval is called. can somebody help me.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTimeout instead:

```
function startSwitchPages(){
    setTimeout(pageOne, 20000);
};

function pageOne(){
    var path='graph1.jsp';
    window.location.href = path;
    setTimeout(pageSecond, 20000);
};

function pageSecond(){
    var path='graph2.jsp';
    window.location.href = path;
    setTimeout(pageOne, 20000);
};
```

Comment: Still it is not calling pageSecond function.

Comment: Does for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6egZA/ but if you are reloading the page it would require two different scripts on two different pages.

Comment: thnx, but it would great if explain little more. which two different script for different pages

Comment: Your first script is removed from the browser when you navigate to the next page, right? So the first page you set an timeout that loads page two, on page two you set a timeout that loads page one. hep!

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect to call the second function when the page is already redirected. this is totally wrong

Comment: Yes, I understood my problem then what is way to sort out this

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
setInterval(function(){pageOne(),pageSecond()},20000)
```